# Laravel [Redis::subscribe] - Read error on connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:6382

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I'm trying to set up communication between php and node.js via redis channels. After executing the `php artisan redis:subscribe` command, everything works for about 10 seconds and I receive messages from the node.js, and after that the following error appears:

```
RedisException 

read error on connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:6382

at ----\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Redis\Connections\PhpRedisConnection.php:463 
    459▕     public function subscribe($channels, Closure $callback)
    460▕     {
    461▕         $this->client->subscribe((array) $channels, function ($redis, $channel, $message) use ($callback) {
    462▕             $callback($message, $channel);
  ➜ 463▕         });
    464▕     }
    465▕
    466▕     /**
    467▕      * Subscribe to a set of given channels with wildcards.

1   ----\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Redis\Connections\PhpRedisConnection.php:463
      Redis::subscribe(Object(Closure))

2   ----\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Redis\RedisManager.php:276
      Illuminate\Redis\Connections\PhpRedisConnection::subscribe(Object(Closure))
```

This is my RedisSubscribe.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class RedisSubscribe extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'redis:subscribe';

    protected $description = 'Subscribe to a Redis channel';

    public function handle()
    {
        Redis::subscribe(['test-channel'], function ($message) {
            echo "Message received: $message";
        });
    }
}
```

This is my redis config in config/database.php file:

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
        'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
    ],

    'default' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        'read_timeout' => 0
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
    ],

]
```

The docker container with redis works fine, the connection works fine from php and from the node.js. Port, scheme, password are correct. It just works fine for 10-15 seconds and displays messages with echo from the node to the console, and then stops working and displays this error.

Comment: is there anything in the log of the redis container?

Comment: @pibocik125 did you manage to solve this issue ?